# cant set different EXPECT_CALL on a single mock object's only function

Tags: c++, mocking, googlemock

I have a network api function `send`, that needs to be mocked with following signature.

```
virtual void send(const RestRequest &req, RestResponse &resp) = 0;
```

This call returns the response in the out param RestResponse.
In my test code, this call is expected to be called 2 times, but obviously with different input `req`
and different output as response in out param `resp`.

I set my expectations as follows:

```
RestRequest ReqObj1= createRequest();
RestRequest ReqObj2= createRequest();
RestResponse RespObj1 = createResponse();
RestResponse RespObj2 = createResponse();

{
        InSequence seq;
        EXPECT_CALL(*mockedConn, send(ReqObj1,_))
        .WillOnce(SetArgReferee<1>(RespObj1));
        EXPECT_CALL(*mockedConn, send(ReqObj2,_))
        .WillOnce(SetArgReferee<1>(RespObj2));
}
```

The first `send` gets mocked fine, and i get the outparam set as RespObj1, but the second call does
not get mocked. Looks like gmock cant differentiate b/w the expectations mentioned, and one overshadows the other.

How do i tell gmock to treat the two expectations seperately?

Comment: It could have to do with `RestRequest`'s equality operator. Can it actually differentiate, or does `ReqObj1 == ReqObj2`?

Comment: GMock *can* differentiate expectation when they *differ* in matchers list. It would get shadowed if you had exactly the same list of matchers for call. What do you mean by "second call does not get mocked"?